# How do I get a count of connections to my Xero App?

Tags: xero-api

Xero limits uncertified apps to connect to only [25 organisations](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/limits).
Where can I access Xero's count of how many connections I have?

I haven't been able to find an API call to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Received the answer from a Xero D/E during a recent webinar:

---

With the token sets you have stored for your users who have connected - you can hit the /connections endpoint for each token to get an accurate number of connections per token.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow

In addition, there is a history tab in the /myapps dashboard that  shows you your API traffic from the past 30 days.

If you still need help you can ping your D/E to understand how to track your API connections by emailing api@xero.com

---

They also confirmed that there is not currently any UI view showing this count.